# Twilo chat (JavaScript API): Unable to delete a channel by its creator after reconnecting to the same channel

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I performed the following steps:

1. Connect to the app as client (for eg. with name Adam).
2. Add a new channel (for eg. with name Channel1).
3. Leave the channel.
4. Again, reconnect to app (as Adam).
5. Delete the channel (Channel1).

I am getting the following error (at step 5 mentioned above):
"User unauthorized for command"

Hence, the creator of channel is unable to delete it.

Code for deleting channel is:

```js
   

 function deleteCurrentChannel() {
    if (!tc.currentChannel) {
      return;
    }

    if (tc.currentChannel.sid === tc.defaultChannel.sid) {
      alert('You cannot delete the default channel');
      return;
    }
    
    tc.currentChannel.delete().then(function(channel) {
      setupChannel(tc.joinDefaultChannel);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err.message);
    });
  }
```

On Chrome Dev tools console I tried to check values and got the results as impled below:

- currentChannel => Channel1
- messagingClient => Adam
- currentChannel.createdBy => Adam

The creator of the channel must be able to remove the channel. How can this be achieved in this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think this has to do with the roles and permissions of the member object involved here. A member can only delete the channel if they have a role that has the [`destroyChannel` permission](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/permissions).

To ensure that the creator of a channel can delete it, you must ensure that each time the user joins the channel you give its member object a role that has permission to destroy the channel.

Let me know if that helps at all.